# Makefile autodeps warning in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

When and why is this warning shown-
"Makefile autodeps: ambiguous include (more than one matching file found)"

Comment: Your project might contain more than one file with the same name. It is hard to predict which one will be used.

Comment: The project doesn't contain more than one file with the same name. Is it happening because I have copied src folder of veins in my project? Though the projects are certainly different.

Answer (score 0):

The autodepend script throws this message if inside your project there are two .h files with the same name, but in different directory AND in your .cc files you just include them without a path prefix (i.e. #include "filename.h"). The dependency generator cannot figure out which file of the two you intended to include.

Comment: According to what you answered sir, I made a new project and copied all the files of my previous project without any directory hierarchy (i.e. all the files are now present in the main project folder only), still it is showing same error. What could be the reason?

Comment: So you are only building your own files now? You removed the files of Veins from your project, removed or closed all other projects, etc?

Comment: No I copied all the files of veins as well. But yes other projects like my previous project and MiXiM were open. And so now I tried building the project again by closing MiXiM (on which my project was dependent) and I succeeded. The error has been resolved now. :) Thanks a bunch.